# On express/review/ page revel if the user passed from onepage

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal-express

I have a shop with paypal express checkout, so the user can checkout directly from poduct page and cart page with the paypal yellow button, but they can also go through onepage checkout and select paypal as payment method..

all paypal  users are redirected on paypal review page...

In the review page I want to identify if the user has passed through onepage or not.

Thanks 
M.